# Windows 7 wont let me install a MSI

Tags: windows-7, installation, windows-installer

Windows 7 wont let me install new software as it says another install is in progress.  There is no known install running and msiexec.exe is not running.  Any ideas?

Update:  after some poking around it appears the .net fw 4 is corrupted and after some googling im attempting a fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trial and error, I deleted the windows\softwaredistributions folder and deleted all the failed installs from the root of the C: drive.  that seemed to do the trick.